# What is the difference in usage between “Möhre” and “Karotte”?

Tags: word-usage, difference

I've been doing a bit of German practice and encountered the words *Möhre* and *Karotte.* Supposedly, they both mean *carrot,* but I can’t see where these would differ in usage. Any ideas?

Comment: I tend to use "Karotten", as I still can't always remember whether "Möhren" is the correct word, or if it's "Mohren", which has a **very** different meaning.

Comment: In colloquial usage, _alte Möhre_ also refers to an old run-down car. I've never heard anyone use _alte Karotte_ or _alte Mohrrübe_ in that sense. I'm a native speaker from the Mohrrüben region.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The use differs from region to region.

The linguistic atlas *[Atlas zur deutschen Alltagssprache](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/mohre/)* shows the areas of distribution of *„Möhre“*, *„Karotte“*, and other variants:

[image: Atlas zur deutschen Alltagssprache]

Comment: In Austria everyone says 'Karotte'. 'Möhre' is considered German German here :)

Comment: @geuetzel: apart from those two blue guys. Maybe they're just visiting ;-)

Comment: We are from Hamburg (now living in Bavaria) and we use *Wurzel*

Comment: It's interesting how you can still see the kingdoms of old in this map.

Comment: Although in Germany according to that map _Möhre_ should be more popular than _Karotte_, there are both of them in product names. See [Möhrensaft](https://shop.rewe.de/getraenke/moehrensaft/schneekoppe-moehrensaft-330ml/PD5804205) and [Karottensaft](https://shop.rewe.de/getraenke/moehrensaft/rewe-bio-karottensaft-mit-apfelsaft-honig-0-5l/PD999977) in the Rewe super market chain online shop. The former is a brand product and the second one is the chain's own biological products line. Both of them share the SEO keyword _moehrensaft_ in the URL though. So maybe that one is more popular after all.

Comment: obligatory upvote for citing "Atlas zur Deutschen Alltagssprache" :-)

Comment: @Raphael Not necessarily kingdom though. Regional differences exist regardless of whether there was a separate regime or not. In China and the US things have always been under one central regime theoretically but still regional dialects vary greatly. Though I get your point.

Answer (score 21):

In theory they  have  different meanings: [*Möhre*](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6hre_(Pflanzenart)) is the species (Daucus carota), and [*Karotte*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karotte) is one subspecies (sativus) of Möhre, but as the Karotte is the only commonly cultivated form subspecies of Möhre, they are synonyms as long as you are not talking to a biologist.

Answer (score 17):

I'm from the southwest where "gelbe Rübe" is a commonly used term (see Loongs post), but in my experience it's not really in use elsewhere and people might have difficulties understanding it.

"Möhre" and "Karotte" are both pretty well understood everywhere in my experience, so you should be able to use whichever.

If I know nothing about the audience (i.e. regional preference), I'd personally use "Karotte" for more formal settings (e.g. scientific work) and "Möhre" for more informal settings (e.g. childrens books or restaurant menus), simply because "Möhre" sounds softer than "Karotte". This is entirely subjective though and might be caused by the order in which I was exposed to the different terms.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference in meaning, but these two as well as the missing third term *gelbe Rübe* have (in my opinion: strongly) different regional distribution. So in conversation, simply switch to the other term if receiving strange glimpses.

Answer (score 2):

As others already said there is no difference in the meaning of *Möhre* vs. *Karotte* apart from a regional different preference in usage.

When looking at the etymology of these words we may find a clue as to why there are so many apparently different words for the same thing in contemporary German.

The oldest words are [*Möhre*](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=M%C3%B6hre) and [*Rübe*](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&hitlist=&patternlist=&lemid=GR08441#XGR08441) that were already known in Old High German (*mor(a)ha* and *ruoba*), used for almost every edible plant root (*Wurzel*) in those days. Regionally *[Wurzel](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=Wurzel)* is also used for a carrot until today.

To sub-classify these edible roots we used their color with *Rübe*, hence the terms *weiße Rübe*, *gelbe Rübe* (the color orange was not yet defined those days), or *rote Rübe* (used for beet**root**).

This color code is present untit today but at the time the color scheme was applied in some regions, other regions started to exclusively use *Möhre* for carrots. This also is why we have the mixed-up term *Mohrrübe*.

[*Karotte*](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=Karotte) on the other hand is a relatively new word introduced as a loanword from French *carotte* (from Latin *carota*) by the end of the 16. Century. It is used until today, sometimes in parallel with the older terms, including the botanical term *daucus **carota** sativus*.