# Warum wird eine "Karotte" regional als "Gelbe Rübe" bezeichnet?

Tags: word-usage, etymology

Gestern wurde hier nach dem [Unterschied zwischen einer Karotte und einer Möhre](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/27459/1224) gefragt. Beim Lesen der Antworten fiel mir auf, dass dort die Bezeichnung "Gelbe Rübe" erwähnt wurde, welche ich bis dato noch nie gehört habe.

Mein erster Gedanke war: Warum *gelb*?

Natürlich gibt es Karotten in leicht variierender Farbe und ich hab auch schon einige im gelblichen Ton in der Hand gehabt, aber wenn ich eine Karotte beschreiben müsste, würde ich einzig zur Farbe *orange* greifen.

Nun hat eine Google-Suche ergeben, dass die orange-farbene Karotte eher eine Züchtung ist, die es ursprünglich nicht gab. Ursprüngliche Farben der Karotte schließen gelb ein, jedoch werden auch violett und weiß aufgezählt.

Außerdem wird in vereinzelten Foren angegeben, dass die Bezeichnung *gelbe Rübe* regional wiederum doch etwas anderes als die *Karotte* bezeichnen kann.

- Warum also *gelbe Rübe* und nicht *weiße*, *violette* oder eben — neuzeitgemäß — *orangene Rübe*?
- Bezeichnet nun also die *gelbe Rübe* wirklich überall eine *Karotte*, oder wird in bestimmten Regionen zwischen den orangenen und den gelblich-weißlichen Rüben unterschieden? (Mit *überall* meine ich hier natürlich nur jene Regionen, wo der Begriff überhaupt Verwendung findet.)

Comment: ich habe gerade keine quelle, aber ist es nicht so, dass "orange" als eigenständige farbwahrnehmung eher neu ist (im dt. zumindest) und das vorher alles unter gelb/rot lief. (Theorie zwei: Die wurden mit der Zeit "oranger" gezüchtet, weil das besser läuft, vgl. Tomaten)

Comment: @Bort, stimmt: http://www.slate.com/articles/podcasts/lexicon_valley/2014/09/lexicon_valley_the_etymology_and_history_of_the_word_orange_with_lexicographer.html

Comment: Dazu passt auch, dass auf der Ampel ein "Gelb" ist, was für mich eher nach Orange aussieht ;)

Comment: Es gibt ja auch „schwarze Bretter“, die eine ganz andere Farbe haben. Häufig sind sie noch nicht einmal Bretter.

Comment: Achtung: "Gelbe Rübe" ist extrem regional abhängig. In Wien handelt es sich dabei um eine Karottenähnliche Wurzel, aber eben gelb und meist etwas größer, etwas anders im Geschmack. Im Internet ist dazu aber erstaunlich wenig zu finden, und außerhalb Österreichs könnte es schwierig werden, eine zu bekommen. Bei meiner Suche habe ich dann gesehen, dass eine "gelbe Rübe" in weiten Teilen Deutschlands eine Karotte ist, aber in der Schweiz eine Steckrübe.

Comment: @SebastianRedl Das bezieht sich ja auf meine zweite Frage. Daraus kann man eine Antwort machen, wenn du das noch ein wenig ausarbeitest ;)

Comment: Wenn ich Kind war sagten viele auf Schwedisch nicht "orange" sondern ""brandgul", was so viel wie "brandgelb" heißt. Heute ist das Wort nicht mehr bräuchlich. Gibt es das Wort brandgelb auch auf Deutsch? – Beta just now   edit

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Karotten gibt es in vielen Farben](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:Carrots_of_many_colors.jpg), allerdings war die gelbe Farbvariante (*Gelbe Rübe*) ab dem 16. Jahrhundert in Europa am häufigsten. Auch als die orangefarbigen Carotin-Möhre sich anfing durchzusetzen, wurde die *Gelbe Rübe* noch als Futterpflanze angebaut. ([Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karotte#Kulturgeschichte))

Hier ein Abschnitt aus dem Wikipediaartikel zur [Kulturgeschichte der Karotte](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karotte#Kulturgeschichte):

> Im 10. Jahrhundert wurden im heutigen Iran rotviolette und gelbe
>   Möhren gezogen, diese gelangten im 12. Jahrhundert nach Spanien und
>   weiter nach Italien. Die rotviolette Möhre wurde in Frankreich und
>   Deutschland zwar bis ins 19. Jahrhundert angebaut, allerdings
>   herrschte in Europa seit dem 16. Jahrhundert die *Gelbe Rübe* vor. Diese
>   wurde auch nach der Durchsetzung der orangefarbigen Carotin-Möhre noch
>   lange als Futterpflanze angebaut.

Warum aber kein Nameswechsel, als orange anfing häufiger zu werden als gelb?

- Ich spekuliere jetzt einfach mal, dass die Leute zu faul waren, sich um die Namensgebung bei verschiedenen Farben zu streiten. *Ist das jetzt schon orange oder noch gelb?* ;)
- Außerdem ging es auch nicht das *Gelb* in *Gelbe Rübe* einfach wegzulassen.  [Rübe](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%BCbe) ist der Überbegriff für eine ganze Reihe von Wurzelgemüsen und Verwechslungen mit anderen Rübensorten wären die Folge gewesen.

Bezüglich der Frage, ob eine *Gelbe Rübe* wirklich überall eine Karotte auszeichnet: In Baden-Württemberg ist eine *Gelbe Rübe* eine ganz normale orangene Karotte. Tatsächlich würde ich auch eine lilafarbene Karotte als *lilafarbene Gelbe Rübe* bezeichnen.

Answer (score 6):

Um die zweite Hälfte Süddeutschlands, in der *Gelbe Rübe* (besser: *Goibe Riam*) verwendet wird, abzudecken: Ja, auch im bairischen Dialekt wird das Wort verwendet, wobei in der standarddeutschen Umgangssprache *Karotte* auch sehr verbreitet ist. Im Dialekt ausschließlich *Goibe Riam* (die, je nach Gegend in Bayern, natürlich anders klingen können).

Es gibt auch andere Rüben, wie zum Beispiel die [Steckrübe](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steckr%C3%BCbe) oder die [Zuckerrübe](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zuckerr%C3%BCbe). Wie Iris schon erwähnt hat, waren die ersten in Europa angebauten Rüben wahrscheinlich gelb und lilafarben. Die orangefarbene konnte sich erst später durchsetzen, hat aber die gelbe Variation vollständig verdrängt.

Die Farbe *orange* – wie auch *lila, rosa* und einige andere – ist eine relativ junge Wortschöpfung, Die Orange ist erst im Mittelalter mit den Kreuzfahrern nach Europa gekommen, und wahrscheinlich über Frankreich nach Deutschland, denn das Wort *Orange* leitet sich direkt vom französischen *orange* ab, welches sich wiederum über viele Zwischenstufen bis zum Sanskrit नारङ्ग (*nāraṅga*) zurückverfolgen lässt. Das Wort [*Orange*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Orange#Orange_.28Deutsch.29) lässt sich erst ab dem 17. Jahrhundert nachweisen – zu einer Zeit als die Gelbe Rübe wahrscheinlich schon längst die vorherrschende Rübensorte war.

Der Weg des Wortes vom Namen der Frucht zum Namen einer Farbe, und weiter zum Adjektiv dieser Farbe ist noch viel weiter, und bis heute noch nicht vollständig abgeschlossen: Viele Leute weigern sich, *orange* als attributives Adjektiv zu verwenden, und sagen stattdessen *orangefarben* oder *orangefarbig* – die alte Form *gelb-rot* ist nach meiner Erfahrung nicht mehr in Gebrauch.

Daher kann man schließen, dass es nicht *Orange Rübe* heißt, weil die Farbe *Orange* an sich noch so jung ist (und das Adjektiv dazu noch viel jünger).

Comment: wie du erwähnt hast, ist gelb-rot anscheinend nicht mehr im Gebrauch. Meine Großeltern sind jedoch sehr konservativ und weigern sich gegen solche Neuheiten im deutschen Sprachgebrauch wie „orange“. Ist es möglich, die Begrifflichkeit rot-gelb zu verwenden? Oder ist selbst dies aus der Mode?

Comment: Wenn ich Kind war sagten viele auf Schwedisch nicht "orange" sondern ""brandgul", was so viel wie "brandgelb" heißt. Heute ist das Wort nicht mehr bräuchlich. Gibt es das Wort brandgelb auch auf Deutsch?

Comment: @Beta In diesem Satz sollte *als* stehen, nicht *wenn*. Und um deine Frage zu beantworten, müsste ich wahrscheinlich deutlich älter sein, als ich bin. Mir sagt »brandgelb« nichts, aber vielleicht anderen, älteren Nutzern hier.

Comment: @Beta : Es gibt zwar feuerrot, aber brandgelb oder auch feuergelb habe ich noch nie gehört oder gelesen.

Comment: Zur Farbe orange / gelb-rot / brandgelb (gemäss User "Beta" früher schwedisch brandgul):
Ich kenne brandgelb für orange auf Deutsch nur in einem Zusammenhang: die schweizerischen Eisenbahnen bezeichneten früher (vermutlich 1935 bis vor 1982) orange Signallichter offiziell als "brandgelb". Heutzutage als "orange". Die in den Eisenbahnsignalen verwendete Farbe scheint mir etwas röter zu sein als das Gelb der Strassenverkehrsampeln - letzteres bezeichnen wir in der Schweiz umgangssprachlich aber auch häufig als orange.
Die deutschen Eisenbahnen bezeichnen ihre orangen Signallichter übrigens als "

Answer (score 0):

Im Osten Österreichs ist mit *»gelbe Rübe«* ausschließlich eine Rübe von gelber Färbung gemeint. Mit *»Karotte«* werden nur die orangen und dunkleren Sorten bezeichnet. Wenn ein Österreicher eine orange Karotte als *gelbe Rübe* bezeichnet, muss die Beleuchtung schon sehr schlecht sein.

Im folgenden Bild sieht man, nach der in Wien, Niederösterreich, der Steiermark und dem Burgenland üblichen Diktion, oben und unten je eine gelbe Rübe, während in der Mitte eine Karotte liegt:

[image: Eine Karotte zwischen zwei gelben Rüben]

Inwiefern diese Unterscheidung auch außerhalb der genannten Region gemacht wird, entzieht sich meiner Kenntnis. Mir war bis heute nicht einmal bekannt, dass es Regionen gibt, in denen *»gelbe Rübe«* auch als Synonym für die orange Karotte verwendet wird.

Bei den selteneren Färbungen gilt im Osten Österreichs diese Faustregel:

- dunkle Sorten (rot, violett, schwarz) heißen *»Karotten«* (*»violette Karotten«, »schwarze Karotten«*)
- helle Sorten (gelb, weiß) heißen *»Rüben«* (*»gelbe Rüben«, »weiße Rüben«*)
- Wenn von einer *»Karotte«* die Rede ist, deren Farbe nicht ausdrücklich genannt wird, ist damit immer eine orange Karotte gemeint.

---

**Rote Rübe**

Das war zwar nicht explizit gefragt, liegt thematisch aber so nahe, dass ich es auch ansprechen will:

In Osten Österreichs wird der Begriff *»rote Rübe«* so gut wie gar nicht verwendet. In dieser Region ist nämlich unklar, was damit gemeint sein könnte.

Die Wurzeln, die hier in der linken Bildhälfte zu sehen ist, bezeichnet man im Osten Österreichs als *»rote Karotten«*. Die Knollen in der rechten Bildhälfte (die übrigens eher violett als rot sind) nennt man hier *»Rohnen«*:

[image: Rote Karotten und Rohnen]

Übrigens: Der Begriff »rote Bete« kommt im aktiven Wortschatz eines Österreichers praktisch gar nicht vor (nur wenn wir mit Deutschen reden, die uns sonst nicht verstehen würden). In der Rangliste der unsympathischsten Wörter, die man von Deutschen manchmal hört, kommt »rote Bete« gleich hinter »Quark« (»Topfen« in Österreich) und »Eisbein« (»Stelze«), ungefähr gleich auf mit der »Apprikose« (»Marille«).